# Python PyQt5 troubles, related to QPushButton and QmenuBar

Tags: python, pyqt5

Ok, so first I'd like to preface this with the fact that I have asked essentially the same question before and it has been closed each time. Either due to not having an MRE or due to "being answered elsewhere". I have checked just about every link on the first two pages of google trying to resolve these issues. I don't know what I'm missing, I'm basically a noob at this. Additionally my only tool I can use for this is a text editor. I cannot use QtDesigner. With that preface over with, here goes.

I have tried to implement a menu bar at the top of my application, nothing seems to happen at all. like at all. not matter what way I try. And since there is nothing to reproduce here, I cannot provide an MRE. Please do not close this question for this.
My button icon is also far too small, I don't care if it becomes a label that is clickable or what. So long as it can connect to a function.
Here's my code:

```py
import json
import math
import os
import PyQt5
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys
from importlib import import_module

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Grandier Calcutron")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('icon.ico'))
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 2000, 992)
        self.Welcome_Message()

    def Welcome_Message(self):
        global __Format__
        Y = 10
        X = 100
        Scale_X = 120
        Scale_Y = 30
        welcome_message = QLabel("Welcome to the Grandier Calcutron!", self)
        welcome_message.setFont(QFont("Arial",16))
        welcome_message.move(700, 300)
        tutorial_message_1 = QLabel("Import a deck to begin!\nFormatting examples are in the sample files.", self)
        tutorial_message_1.setFont(QFont("Arial",16))
        tutorial_message_1.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        tutorial_message_1.move(660, 340)
        Import_Deck = QPushButton(self)
        Import_Sym = QPixmap("symbols/import_sym")
        Import_Sym = QIcon(Import_Sym)
        Import_Deck.setIcon(Import_Sym)
        Import_Deck.clicked.connect(self.import_click)
        Import_Deck.clicked.connect(welcome_message.hide)
        Import_Deck.clicked.connect(tutorial_message_1.hide)
        Import_Deck.clicked.connect(Import_Deck.hide)
        Import_Deck.move(10, 10)
        Import_Deck.resize(100, 100)
        stats_button = QPushButton("Stats", self)
        stats_button.move(250, Y)
        stats_button.resize(120, 30)
        formats = ["Commander", "Oath Breaker", "Standard", "Free-Form", "Artisan", "Prismatic"]
        self.combo = QComboBox(self)
        for i in formats:
            self.combo.addItem(i)
        self.combo.move(370,Y+1)
        self.combo.resize(120, 28)
        __Format__ = self.combo.currentText()

    def display_color_event(self):
        X = 30
        Y = 10
        if len(fmtda.deck_id_res) == 5:
            if 'G' in fmtda.deck_id_res and 'U' in fmtda.deck_id_res and 'R' in fmtda.deck_id_res and 'B' in fmtda.deck_id_res and 'W' in fmtda.deck_id_res:
                color_icon = QPixmap("symbols/WUBRG.PNG")
            color_icon_label = QLabel(self)
            color_icon = color_icon.scaled(100, 100, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.FastTransformation)
            color_icon_label.setPixmap(color_icon)
            color_icon_label.move(X, Y)
            color_icon_label.show()
        elif len(fmtda.deck_id_res) == 4:
            if 'W' not in fmtda.deck_id_res:
                color_icon = QPixmap("symbols/UBRG.PNG")
            elif 'U' not in fmtda.deck_id_res:
                color_icon = QPixmap("symbols/BRGW.PNG")
            elif 'B' not in fmtda.deck_id_res:
                color_icon = QPixmap("symbols/RGWU.PNG")
            elif 'R' not in fmtda.deck_id_res:
                color_icon = QPixmap("symbols/GWUB.PNG")
            elif 'G' not in fmtda.deck_id_res:
                color_icon = QPixmap("symbols/WUBR.PNG")
        else:
            if fmtda.deck_id_res == ['W','U'] or fmtda.deck_id_res == ['U','W']:
                color_icon = QPixmap("symbols/WU.PNG")
            elif fmtda.deck_id_res == ['U','B'] or fmtda.deck_id_res == ['B','U']:
                color_icon = QPixmap("symbols/UB.PNG")
            elif fmtda.deck_id_res == ['B','R'] or fmtda.deck_id_res == ['R','B']:
                color_icon = QPixmap("symbols/BR.PNG")
            elif fmtda.deck_id_res == ['R','G'] or fmtda.deck_id_res == ['G','R']:
                color_icon = QPixmap("symbols/RG.PNG")
            elif fmtda.deck_id_res == ['W','G'] or fmtda.deck_id_res == ['G','W']:
                color_icon = QPixmap("symbols/GW.PNG")
            elif fmtda.deck_id_res == ['B','W'] or fmtda.deck_id_res == ['W','B']:
                color_icon = QPixmap("symbols/BW.PNG")
            elif fmtda.deck_id_res == ['U','R'] or fmtda.deck_id_res == ['R','U']:
                color_icon = QPixmap("symbols/UR.PNG")
            elif fmtda.deck_id_res == ['B','G'] or fmtda.deck_id_res == ['G','B']:
                color_icon = QPixmap("symbols/BG.PNG")
            elif fmtda.deck_id_res == ['R','W'] or fmtda.deck_id_res == ['W','R']:
                color_icon = QPixmap("symbols/RW.PNG")
            elif fmtda.deck_id_res == ['U','G'] or fmtda.deck_id_res == ['G','U']:
                color_icon = QPixmap("symbols/UG.PNG")
            elif 'U' in fmtda.deck_id_res and 'G' in fmtda.deck_id_res and 'W' in fmtda.deck_id_res:
                color_icon = QPixmap("symbols/GWU.PNG")
            elif 'U' in fmtda.deck_id_res and 'B' in fmtda.deck_id_res and 'W' in fmtda.deck_id_res:
                color_icon = QPixmap("symbols/WUB.PNG")
            elif 'U' in fmtda.deck_id_res and 'B' in fmtda.deck_id_res and 'R' in fmtda.deck_id_res:
                color_icon = QPixmap("symbols/UBR.PNG")
            elif 'G' in fmtda.deck_id_res and 'R' in fmtda.deck_id_res and 'B' in fmtda.deck_id_res:
                color_icon = QPixmap("symbols/GRB.PNG")
            elif 'R' in fmtda.deck_id_res and 'G' in fmtda.deck_id_res and 'W' in fmtda.deck_id_res:
                color_icon = QPixmap("symbols/RGW.PNG")
            elif 'W' in fmtda.deck_id_res and 'B' in fmtda.deck_id_res and 'G' in fmtda.deck_id_res:
                color_icon = QPixmap("symbols/WBG.PNG")
            elif 'U' in fmtda.deck_id_res and 'R' in fmtda.deck_id_res and 'W' in fmtda.deck_id_res:
                color_icon = QPixmap("symbols/URW.PNG")
            elif 'B' in fmtda.deck_id_res and 'G' in fmtda.deck_id_res and 'U' in fmtda.deck_id_res:
                color_icon = QPixmap("symbols/BGU.PNG")
            elif 'G' in fmtda.deck_id_res and 'U' in fmtda.deck_id_res and 'R' in fmtda.deck_id_res:
                color_icon = QPixmap("symbols/GUR.PNG")
            elif fmtda.deck_id_res == ['W']:
                color_icon = QPixmap("symbols/W.PNG")
            elif fmtda.deck_id_res == ['U']:
                color_icon = QPixmap("symbols/U.PNG")
            elif fmtda.deck_id_res == ['B']:
                color_icon = QPixmap("symbols/B.PNG")
            elif fmtda.deck_id_res == ['R']:
                color_icon = QPixmap("symbols/R.PNG")
            elif fmtda.deck_id_res == ['G']:
                color_icon = QPixmap("symbols/G.PNG")
            else:
                color_icon = QPixmap("symbols/C.png")
        color_icon_label = QLabel(self)
        new_color_icon = color_icon.scaled(100, 100, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.FastTransformation)
        color_icon_label.setPixmap(new_color_icon)
        color_icon_label.move(X, Y)
        color_icon_label.show()

    def import_click(self):
        self.openFileNameDialog()
        ext = os.path.splitext(deckFile)[-1].lower()
        if ext == ".cmdr":
            fmtda.commander.decklist_import(deckFile)
            self.decklist_display(formatword="commander")
        elif ext == ".oath":
            fmtda.oathbreaker.decklist_import(deckFile)     
            self.decklist_display(formatword="oath-breaker")       
        elif ext == ".stand":
            fmtda.standard.decklist_import(deckFile)   
            self.decklist_display()     
        elif ext == ".free":
            fmtda.free_form.decklist_import(deckFile)        
            self.decklist_display()
        elif ext == ".arti":
            fmtda.artisan.decklist_import(deckFile)      
            self.decklist_display()  
        elif ext == ".pris":
            fmtda.prismatic.decklist_import(deckFile)
            self.decklist_display()
        self.display_color_event()

    def decklist_display(self, formatword="nil"):
        lis = fmtda.base_decklist
        commanderlis = fmtda.commanders
        Y_BASE = 120
        X_BASE = 20
        X = 20
        X2 = 18
        Y = 120
        Y2 = 100
        for num, card in lis:
            if card in commanderlis:
                label = QLabel(f"{card} is your {formatword}", self)
                print(f"{card} is your {formatword}")
            else:
                label = QLabel(f"{num}x {card}", self)
            pixmap = QPixmap("UI/namebox.png")
            image = QLabel(self)
            pixmap = pixmap.scaled(200, 30, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.FastTransformation)
            image.setPixmap(pixmap)
            image.move(X2, Y2)
            image.show
            label.setFont(QFont("Arial",12))
            label.move(X, Y)
            label.show()
            Y = Y+26
            Y2 = Y2+30
            if Y > (Y_BASE)+26*31:
                Y = Y_BASE
                X = X+333
        Y = Y_BASE
        X = X_BASE
        for card in commanderlis:
            label = QLabel(f"{card} is your {formatword}", self)
            print(f"{card} is your {formatword}")
            label.setFont(QFont("Arial",12))
            label.move(X+120, Y-30)
            label.show()
            Y = Y+26
            Y2 = Y2+30
            if Y > (Y_BASE)+26*31:
                Y = Y_BASE
                X = X+333
    
    def openFileNameDialog(self):
        global deckFile
        deckfile = 0
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()", "","Commander files (*.cmdr);;Oath Breaker files (*.oath);;Standard files (*.stand);;Free Form files (*.free);;Artisan files (*.arti);;Prismatic files (*.pris)", options=options)
        deckFile = fileName


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

screen = Window()
screen.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The fancy filetypes should be irrelevant since they only apply after the button should disappear. As with all the extra code referenced from `ftmda`. I hope all this suffices to make this question. Again, I can't give any other information aside from that if it is *really* needed.

Edit: I have resolved the button issue. All it took was:

```py
        stats_button.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 20px;")
        stats_button.setIconSize(QSize(60, 60))
```

Edit 2: Solution to Menubar issues; QWidget does not have access to `menuBar()`, in addition to me not having a layout.

Comment: The "reproducible" part in [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) does not mean that it should show what you want to do, but that it is able to *reproduce your issue*. If you miss relevant parts of your code (such as the whole `fmtda` which is used in almost half of tour example), and you don't even explain what it does, we cannot just "guess" what's wrong with your problem. Then again, if that part is irrelevant, why include it? "Minimal" means that only the *relevant* parts should be added.

Comment: @musicmante the part I had trouble with on the "reproducible" is there is nothing to reproduce at all. I left all the references to `fmtda` because it runs just fine as I pasted it. I would have tried to add an example for the menu bar, but I am simply not going to go through pasting every segment of menu bar code I have tried from various places. It has never even crashed when I added the menu bar code, it simply doesn't work. Even if I did paste all I found, it doesn't do anything visually or in the terminal, I have no clue what to even give you to reproduce.

Comment: In any case, your question is not clear. You say: "nothing seems to happen at all", but it's not clear what are you expecting to happen. I can click on the button on the left and the file dialog correctly appears, then I cannot go further because of those `fmtda` not defined, and I don't even understand what should happen then because you didn't explain what it is and what it does.

Comment: @musicmante the "nothing happens" was for the menubar, my issue with the button was it didn't look right but I have resolved that. I still have no solution to a menu bar. What I am "expecting to happen" with the menubar is that it is visible. (cont)

Comment: It currently isn't. At this point I'm suspicious they are not compatible with how I have `class Window(QWidget):` as all the other samples I have found use something else for where I have QWidget. As for `fmtda` it only reads the chosen file. I would share it but, it's irrelevant to the menubar. I apologize if I'm still being too vague.

Comment: QWidget doesn't provide a menubar, QMainWindow does and it's accessible using [`menuBar()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenubar.html#usage) (which creates a new one if it doesn't exist). You can create a menu bar for a QWidget as long as you add the parent widget in the constructor (`self.menuBar = QMenuBar(self)`) and it'll be placed on the top left of the widget, but you would probably face some problems as you're not using a layout (which you should); if you set a layout for the widget, you can add the menu bar using [`layout.setMenuBar()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#setMenuBar).

Comment: @musicamante I'll attempt switching to QMainWindow and adding a layout then. Hopefully that isn't too difficult. Thank you for helping me!

Comment: I strongly suggest you to carefully study the [QMainWindow](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#details) features and documentation.